# Every paracompact Hausdorff is normal.

Tags: general-topology

I studied from Munkres' *Topology* its proof. He says that the Hausdorff condition enables us to choose, for each $b \in B$ an open set $U_b$ whose closure is disjoint from $a$. I did not get why closure does not intersect $a$ as Hausdorff only says that we can find disjoint open sets or neighbourhoods for each point of a Hausdorff space? Either it is trivial for closed set also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's call our space $X.$ Since $X$ is Hausdorf, then for distinct $a,b\in X,$ there are open sets $U_a$ and $U_b$ with $a\in A_u,$ $b\in U_b,$ and $U_a\cap U_b=\emptyset.$ Thus, $U_b\subseteq X\setminus U_a.$ Since $U_a$ is open, then $X\setminus U_a$ is closed. The closure of $U_b$ is the intersection of all closed supersets of $U_b,$ so the closure of $U_b$ is a subset of $X\setminus U_a,$ so that $U_a$ is disjoint from the closure of $U_b.$ In particular, $a\notin \overline{U_b}.$

Comment: I have an other question that why we are prving that clouser of open set is disjoint from a? is it not enough to show that Ub is disjoint from a?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure, and I don't have the leisure to think about it. If it *were* enough, though, then we'd instead be able to prove the stronger result that every paracompact $T_1$ space is normal. If your suspicion is correct, then that result is true. If that result is false, then it isn't enough that the sets $U_b$ are disjoint from $a.$ You can try asking that as another question here, or dig into how the proof uses paracompactness to see where the disjoint closures might be important.

Comment: @Hafsa Look at [my explanation](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3476126/4280) at the other version of this question and see where it is used.

Comment: I asked an other question and some one told me.